# Constructing maps and composites

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I really need help with set theory. For some reason I just can't seem to grasp it. I understand the definitions, but I have no idea how to do the proofs.
 Here's a question that I'm really stuck on: 
Construct maps $\psi$: $S \to T$ and $\gamma : U \to W$ such that the composite $\gamma\circ \psi$: $S \to W$ is not defined, but the composite $\psi \circ \gamma$: $U \to T$ is defined. 

Any hints or help would be awesome! If you can give an example that would be super great.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** Note that for any maps $\psi$ and $\gamma$, the map $\psi\circ\gamma$ is defined if and only if $\operatorname{im}\gamma\subset\operatorname{dom}\psi$, and the map $\gamma\circ\psi$ is defined if and only if $\operatorname{im}\psi\subset\operatorname{dom}\gamma$.

Suppose you can specify the domain and image of these maps as you please. Can you think of pairs that satisfy these conditions? If so, then try to conjure maps that fit the prescribed domains and images.

Consider the functions whose rules of assignment are $x\mapsto 2x$ and $x\mapsto x/2$ and whose domains are $[0,1]$. Take the range of the first map to be $[0,2]$ and the range of the second map to be $[0,1]$. What are the images of these maps? How do the images lie within the ranges? Are both compositions valid?